# How do I add localization for some fields in a rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, localization, yaml, refinerycms

I am using refinery-cms and have created a custom engine, which houses a jobs model. When I use that model in a form, I add the following code to pull one of the model's fields:

```
     <%= f.label :postingTitle -%>
     <%= f.text_field :postingTitle, :class => 'larger widest'  -%>
```

The example above pulls the postingTitle field. How do I change the label for posting title? I thought it was a case of adding a translation in the en.yml file, which I did and wrote as follow:

```
   activerecord:
     models:
       jobs: jobs
     attributes:
       jobs:
         postingTitle: Job Title
```

But that didn't work - and if I add any more that one attribute I also get a rails error.

Answer (score 0):

you might want to have a look at this gem

https://github.com/joshmh/globalize2

seems to do what you are looking for

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  translates :title, :text
end
```

example (from their readme)

```
I18n.locale = :en
post.title # => Globalize2 rocks!

I18n.locale = :he
post.title # => גלובאלייז2 שולט!
```

Comment: Thanks - I believe RefineryCMS already includes Globalize3 but i still can't get it to work.